# Redirecting page based on <select> value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a `<select>` tag on my site that when I change it submits the form and goes to the page in question where I can use the `$_POST` variable.

```html
<form method='POST' action='myURL'>
<select onchange='this.form.submit();'>
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
</form>
```

This is fine and works as intended but if someone is on the page and refreshes it I don't want to have to have the warning for resubmitting the form.

So what I was trying to do is remove the form element and have something like this and I can use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`.

```html
<select onchange='window.location.href="myURL?var=this.value";'>
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
```

However, this redirects to the page but the `$_GET` variable is literally `this.value`.

Is there another way of getting this to work or will I need to write an external piece of JS for this?

**Note** `JS` isn't my language, the snippets above are all being rendered via `PHP`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've hardcoded the string - just do this instead:

```
<select onchange='window.location.href=("myURL?var=" + this.value);'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to you to avoid the use of inline-events as `onchange` and use the `addEventListener()` method instead to attach the `change` event.

So first give you select tag an identifier (id or class) then attach the event using this identifier like :

```
<select id="my-select">
```

Then in the JS part it could be attached like :

```
document.querySelector('#my-select').addEventListener('change', function(){
    window.location.href = "myURL?var=" + this.value;
})
```

Or if you could use jQuery it will be :

```
$('#my-select').change(function(){
    window.location.href = "myURL?var=" + $(this).val();
})
```